# Correct way to run pip

Tags: python, pip

Is there any difference running package installation for a python project using these two commands?

```
python -m pip install <package>

pip install <package>
```

**NOTE** I'm using `venv` in my project.

Comment: Technically the python and pip on your path could be mismatched for some reason.

Comment: When using virtual environments most probably there is no difference as the 1st `pip` in the `$PATH` almost certainly points to the correct python from the virtual env.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are nearly equivalent but they might point to different python installations (and versions). `python -m pip` gives you more explicit control since you can specify `python3.8 -m pip` and know that you are installing for the Python 3.8 interpreter. This is not explicitly obvious with `pip` without more investigation. Brett Cannon wrote a nice blog post: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

They are probably equivalent.

#### Longer answer

When you run `python -m pip`, you are referencing a module of Python called `pip`. The `python` command will use your installed version of Python (based on your PATH variable) - So the corresponding `pip` version will be used.

When you run `pip install`, a `pip` module is located by searching the PATH variable, and not by using `python`. This **could** be a different pip module than in `python -m pip`, but it usually isn't.

**Edit**: In the case of running under a virtual environment, the PATH variable should contain the virtual environment path, so both will be the same - the `python` that is used will use the `pip` from the same virtual environment.